# Given a subspace $W_1$ of a vector space $V$, find a subspace $W_2$ of $V$ such that $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on following past year exam question:

> Let  $W_1=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)\in \mathbb R^5: x_1 + x_2 +
> + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 0\}$, subspace of the $\mathbb R$-vector space
> $\mathbb R^5$. Find a basis of $W_1$, and determine a subspace $W_2$ of  $\mathbb R^5$ such that $\mathbb R^5
> = W_1 \bigoplus W_2 $.

**My attempt:** I have calculated dim $W_1 = 4$, with a basis $\{(-1, 1, 0, 0, 0). (-1, 0, 1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 0 , 0 , 1)\}$.

**My doubt**: When determining $W_2$, do I simply guess so that $\mathbb R^5$ becomes the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$? One of my guesses is $W_2  = \{(x, 0, 0, 0, 0): x \in \mathbb R\}$. I am uncertain about the correctness of my approach. Kindly help me in solving this type of problem.

Comment: The coefficient vector  of the given equation  is $(1,1,1,1,1)$ and you take $W_2$ to be the span of this  vector: $W_2=\{(x,x,x,x,x):x \in \mathbb R\}$

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for the response.  My solution is right or wrong?

Comment: Yours is also correct.

Comment: If you are familiar with the concept of orthogonal complement you don't have to find a basis. You can answer the question in seconds.

Comment: Alternatively (and more generally), the solution for $W_2$ is: any line not contained in the [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane#Vector_hyperplanes) $W_1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you please write the answer using orthogonal complement. I am familiar with the term but how to apply here? This would add my knowledge. thanks a lot

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for your comment. That was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_1$ is nothing but the orthogonal complement of $(1,1,1,1,1)$. If $M_2$ is the span of this  vector then  we can write $M_1=M_2^{\perp}$.  [$M^{\perp}$ is the notation for the orthogonal complement of $M$]. There is a theorem which says $V=M\oplus M^{\perp}$ ($V$ being $\mathbb R^{5}$ in our case),  which show that we can take $W_2$ to be the span of $(1,1,1,1,1)$.This avoids all computations for answering this question.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. M1 is nothing but orthogonal complement of (1, 1, 1, 1, 1): Is it because inner product  of (1,1, 1, 1,1) to (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) is zero?

Comment: Yes, $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5$ is just the inner product of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ with $(1,1,1,1,1)$. @Srijan

Comment: thanks again for the help